# Як сказати українською "шиворот-навыворот" щодо одягу?

Tags: from-russian

Я пошукав у декількох словниках переклад для "шиворот-навыворот", але не знайшов переклад саме в значенні коли одяг вдягають внутрішнім боком назовні.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> <sub>«Російсько-український словник фразеологізмів (сталих виразів)» /  І. О. Вирган, М. М. Пилинська</sub>
>
> [**Шиворот-навыворот**](http://stalivyrazy.org.ua/everyfile.php?transfer=folders/sh/aivorot.html) (*разг. фам.*).
>
> Навпаки, (*лок*. навверле); шкереберть.

---

Тлуми згаданих слів.

> <sub>Словарь української мови: в 4-х тт. / За ред. Б. Грінченка. — К., 1907—1909. — Т. 2. — С. 467.</sub>
>
> [**Навверле́**](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/29662-navverle.html) *нар*.
>
> 1. Наоборотъ.
> 2. Напрямикъ, не держась дороги (пойти); грубо напрямикъ (сказать). *Сказати павверле*.

> <sub>Словарь української мови: в 4-х тт. / За ред. Б. Грінченка. — К., 1907—1909. — Т. 4. — С. 500.</sub>
>
> [**Шкереберть**](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/65958-shkerebert.html) *нар*.
>
> Вверхъ ногами, вверхъ дномъ. *Полетів шкереберть*. Черк. у. *Усе піде шкереберть*. Шевч. 283. *Сказавши, столик ізвалило, шкереберть к чорту все пішло*. Котл. Ен. V. 30.

Приклад вживу. [*Надіта шкереберть майка — до сварки двох люблячих людей.*](https://ukr.media/esoterics/412311/). Але, справдї, *навпаки* можна тлумити не тіʼко як *внутрішнім боком назовні*, а і як *задом наперед*: [*Наприклад, «День навпаки», коли все можна робити шкереберть: одяг одягати задом наперед […]*.](http://teg.com.ua/chim-zainiatisia-na-karantini-vdoma-z-ditmi-30-sprav-na-byd-iakii-smak/)

---

Тому зазвичай просто кажуть:

> [**НАВИ́ВОРІТ**](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=53496&page=1705), *присл*.
>
> 1. Лицьовим боком усередину, а внутрішнім назовні.
>    *Хороший, як Микитина свита навиворіт* (прислів'я); *– Чи це воно на лице, чи, мабуть, навиворіт? – питала Онися, придивляючись до матерії* (І. Нечуй-Левицький); *Заходить на колгоспний двір якийсь дід. Кожух навиворіт, шапка насунута на очі, сам згорбився, ціпочком поперед себе постукує* (Григорій Тютюнник); * Образно. *Що ж іще могло бути сумнівного в його біографії, яку під час чистки треба показати всім навиворіт?* (Б. Антоненко-Давидович).
>
> […]